# How to change field source in admin-on-rest reactJS

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I have status field the value is `0 and 1` which attribute type is integer, but I need to display as string/ convert to word which 1 is "accepted" and 0 is "rejected".

How do I change it in `<TextField source="status" />` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [`write your own component`](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#writing-your-own-field-component). See example below

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

const CustomTextField = ({ source, record = {} }) => <span>{ (record[source] === 1) ? 'accepted' : 'rejected' }</span>;

CustomTextField.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string,
    record: PropTypes.object,
    source: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default CustomTextField;
```